# How to make wordpress sub menu position always from left?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, nav

Im coding this design on wordpress: http://ft.webmode.lt/

And i got stuck on top sub-meniu floating. When you hover on first menu item the sub-menu floats normal from left, when hover second menu item the sub menu starts from that menu item who is child.

How to make submenu always float from left?

My code i use now: http://pastebin.com/sTt4wB2b

**DONE**

I just remove position:relative; from header .top-meniu ul li and add it to header .top-meniu ul

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way using css:

```
.select-submenu-wrappers {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
```